# Override Zend framework classes in Magento using configuration?

Tags: zend-framework, magento, overriding

Do you know if there is a way in Magento to override classes from Zend framework using configuration like in next example:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mymodule>
            <zend>
                <rewrite>
                    <somezendclass>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_SomeZendClass</somezendclass>
                </rewrite>
            </zend>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.
If you really want to change some class from ZF, you should copy it to `app/code/local/Zend` (path to your class...) directory.
Bad thing is that you should copy and paste whole class.

Comment: See the include path setup in the app bootstrap at `app/Mage.php` as well as the autoloader at `lib/Varien/Autoload.php` for further information.

Comment: FYI, this is how Magento core does it too (granted, with just a single file): https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.6/app/code/core/Zend/Mime.php